# Issue with Recursive Multi-Join Query

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with a recursive multi-join query.
I thinking, and testing many solution, but I waiting for result +1h and nothing.
Anyone have idea, how I can fix it, maybe I should change my database structure?

- query
  https://gist.github.com/mxcdh/d4ea7f98236e4a6ad084b9d1a2eaa7d9#file-postgres_query-sql
- schema.prisma
  https://gist.github.com/mxcdh/d4ea7f98236e4a6ad084b9d1a2eaa7d9#file-schema-prisma
- what I want returned:
  https://gist.github.com/mxcdh/d4ea7f98236e4a6ad084b9d1a2eaa7d9#file-return-md
- database table overview
  https://gist.github.com/mxcdh/d4ea7f98236e4a6ad084b9d1a2eaa7d9#file-database_overview-md

Comment: Please add your data and query to your post, rather than just relying on external links

Answer (score 1):

I believe your main issue is you created an infinite recursion query accidentally.

It could be by `SELECT`ing the wrong instance of parent / child columns in the recursive part of your query. It can also happen with *bad* hierarchy data where the ancestor becomes the child again, e.g. A is parent of B. B is parent of C. C is parent of A. This would cause infinite recursion.

Also, you can reduce the number of joins that actually occur during recursion by removing all non-hierarchical data out of the recursive CTE, and only join to it once at the end with the final results. That improves performance and makes the recursive part more readable, like so:

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_hierarchy AS 
(
    SELECT 
        cc.category_children_id,
        cc.category_parent_id,
        1 AS depth
    FROM category_children_to_category_parent cc

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        cc.category_children_id,
        cc.category_parent_id,
        depth + 1
    FROM category_children_to_category_parent cc
    JOIN category_hierarchy ch 
        ON cc.category_parent_id = ch.category_children_id
)

SELECT
  c.id,
  c.url,
  cd.name,
  ch.depth
FROM category_hierarchy ch
JOIN category c
    ON ch.category_children_id = c.id
JOIN category_data cd 
    ON c.id = cd.main_category_id
ORDER BY
  ch.depth,
  c.id;
```

Comment: thanks but your query not helping, I still waiting and nothing, its normal?
https://dsh.re/4ec02

Comment: @mxcdh I think you had the right reference of columns in your original query. I just updated mine to put them back. The table join order threw me off. Please see my updated query. If it's still hanging, then you probably have some *bad* hierarchy data where an ancestor becomes a child again later on, causing an infinite loop. Verify your data, or try testing on a smaller copy of the tables that you know doesn't have an infinite loop in the hierarchy, to verify the query is correct.

Comment: the model works well and fast on a small amount of data, but not on the whole database. What should I do? Should I change the structure?
---
I made:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/8558

It's look right?

Comment: @mxcdh Again, I think you're running into an infinite recursion issue, not a performance issue. How did you conclude it's fast on a small amount of data but not the whole database?...you tested it with a subset of the original data and it was fast, but with the whole database it never comes back? I have a feeling you have infinitely linked hierarchical data. Generally you should clean that data if so, but there are workarounds you can add to the recursive query too. I'll try to update my answer with a workaround when I get a chance.

Comment: For a small number of records, my rewrite query working, for whole data set not. I've rewritten my query to avoid an infinite loop, but it's still not working on full data set. What do you recommend to avoid an infinite loop?

My rewrite query: https://dsh.re/57e2f

Comment: @mxcdh Does it ever come back on the full dataset now, and it's just slow?...or it still never comes back? The change you made is essentially the type of workaround I was talking about, but I'd have to look closer at your code. Perhaps there's a logical bug with it.

Comment: When I query a small database, I get results instantly (1ms), but on a full database I can wait up to 1 hour and still counting, etc. I think the problem could be with the `category_children_to_category_parent` database, which has 2k categories and 100k entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145923/discussion-between-mxcdh-and-j-d).